# How is the angle of a ship wake measured?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, soft-question

I was wondering how is the angle of a ship wake measured?
I don't really undesrtand how the following images determine the angle of the ship wakes, as there isn't a defined edge.

[image]

Comment: in the pictures you see clearly how the "edge" i constructed. to lines in a plain have an angle, even if the do not meet on a picture.